# Дата публикации php

Tags: php, дата

Нужен скрипт, с помощью которого, можно было бы отображать дату публикации.

Пример: Я добавляю запись через html, ставлю в этой записи переменную (например `date`) и при публикации, около записи отображается дата публикации.

P.S. Понимаю, что возможно много прошу, но я нигде не смог найти ответа. Везде приводятся примеры с сайтами на WordPress.

Comment: Записи, которые вы собираетесь добавлять через php где планируете хранить? Если в базе данных, то никто не мешает вам предусмотреть в таблице с данными поле для хранения даты. И загружать данные потом из этой таблицы вместе с датами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Если вы работаете с базой данных Mysql.**
**1)** Создаете в таблице вашей базы данных отдельное поле с названием `date` к примеру. Ставите в это поле кодировку `utf8_general_ci` и для теста выбираете тип поля, к примеру `TIMESTAMP`. Который сохраняет (день, месяц, год, время)
**2)** В форме ввода записи вставляете поле скрытое `type="hidden" value="date"` (value принимает значение даты).             **3)** Не забываем в скрипте просмотра записи вставить переменную которую достаем из базы данных `date` вот в принципе и все.                                                                      **Если вы работаете в обычном HTML без баз данных**, просто возьмите отдельный тег к примеру `<b> </b>` и в конце каждой записи выставляйте дату вручную.

Answer (score 0):

PHP не нужен. Достаточно разместить скрипт в конец тега <body>. Лучше всего работает если PHP вообще не установлен или не используется.
То есть работает хорошо даже на статичной HTML-страничке на сервере.

```
<script>
// Получаем заголовки текущей страницы
fetch(location,{method:'head'})
  .then(({headers})=>{
    // Получаем заголовок последнего изменения
    const modified = headers.get('last-modified');
    // TODO иногда последнее изменение можно извлечь из заголовка Etag
    // Если последнее изменение известно
    if(modified){
      // Приведем дату в божеский вид
      const localModified = new Date(modified).toLocaleString();
      // ищем текст "date" по всей странице
      findAll('date').forEach(({node,offset:[beg,end]})=>{
        // Если текст "date" найден в одной ноде
        if(!Array.isArray(node)){
          // заменяем "date" на дату из заголовка
          node.replaceData(beg,end-beg, localModified);
        }
      });
    }
  });
// Достаточно дурацкая реализация поиска текста по всей странице
function findAll(text){
  const res = [];
  // Сохраняем позицию скролла
  let pos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  // Сбрасываем что пользователь выделил на странице
  window.getSelection().empty();
  // Пока ищется текст, выполняем
  while(window.find(text)) {
    // Получаем текущее выделение
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    // Нода, в которой начинается найденный текст
    const nodeBeg = sel.anchorNode;
    // Смещение найденного текста от начала ноды (в символах)
    const ofstBeg = sel.anchorOffset;
    // Нода, в которой заканчивается найденный текст
    const nodeEnd = sel.focusNode;
    // Смещение конца найденного текста от начала ноды (в символах)
    const ofstEnd = sel.focusOffset;
    // Добавляем это хозяйство в массив с результатами
    res.push({node: nodeBeg == nodeEnd ? 
                    nodeBeg : 
                    [nodeBeg,nodeEnd],
            offset: [ofstBeg,ofstEnd]});
  }
  // Сбрасываем последнее выделение
  window.getSelection().empty();
  // Восстанавливаем позицию скролла
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = pos;
  // Возвращаем результат
  return res;
}
</script>
```